# Dynamically change mobile content slider width using jquery for portrait and landscape

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I dynamically change the width and height of a content slider that is set using jQuery when the mobile phone is rotated from portrait to landscape? The client is using the "allinone" content slider for their site. The width and height of this content slider is set using jQuery with the following code:

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#allinone_contentSlider_imposing').allinone_contentSlider({
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        });     
    });
```

I would like to dynamically change the width and height of the slider when the phone is switched from portrait to landscape  but my javascript skills are not good enough. I have tried unsuccessfully to define a variable using $(window).width() and the resize() event like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    function updateWidth() {
        var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
    }
    updateWidth();
            $(window).resize(function() {
                updateWidth();
            });
    jQuery('#allinone_contentSlider_imposing').allinone_contentSlider({
        width: $containerWidth,
        height: 300
    });     
});
```

Unfortunately the above code fails to define a width which causes the slider not to display. As an aside, this is not a mobile only website. Perhaps there is a better way to solve this problem. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
vp_width = jQuery(window).width();

if (vp_width <= 650) {
//alert('mobile');

//Add some Jquery here to change the height and width of the banner?


)};
```

Not sure if this helpful, if you know the width of the device you could perhaps target the width as above and then set some CSS? Hope this helps, apologies if not!

Comment: your idea is successful in changing the width initially. But when the phone is turned from portrait to landscape (or vice versa) the browser needs to be refreshed in order to reflect the new change of width. Perhaps I need to bind this to a resize event.